# How to inset edges without using an array modifier, or a premade "plank" object?

Tags: modeling, edges

I have previously made models using Maya to get the intended look but I've forgotten how to actually do this in Maya and prefer Blender when making models anyway. I'm trying to get a planked look for a crate by using inset edges on a high-poly version of the crate to high-low poly bake when texturing. *The intended result is shown in the attached image, on a barrel.*

[image: Barrel with planking indentations]

Comment: you can use the array modifier and the curve modifier for that as well

Answer (score 0):

Add a plank object, then give it an Array modifier.
[image]

In edit mode move the plank some distance away from the origin. This is going to be the radius of your barrel.

[image]

Then in the same location as the origin, add an Empty Object, rotate it on the Z-axis by the number of degrees equal to 360/ your Array count.

[image]

Then just set the Offset type to object and pick the empty object.

[image]